# Awk to multiply consecutive lines

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with a single column with N numbers:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

And I would like to use *awk* to multiply first with second, second with third and so on and then add all these, i.e:

```
(a*b)+(b*c)+(c*d)+...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: post testable input (not a bunch of letters unless you have some way of multiplying letters in mind), expected output, and what you'd tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following command:

```
awk 'NR>1{t+=l*$0}{l=$0}END{print t}' input.txt
```

Having this input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

it will ouput:

```
40
```

which equals `1*2+2*3+3*4+4*5`

Comment: `awk awk`? Is this a new construct ;-)

Comment: You don't know that?! :) Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `NR>1` condition and combine first two blocks. `awk '{t+=l*$0;l=$0}END{print t}'` will do.